# Callback в Activity

Tags: java, android, callback

Доброго времени суток!

Есть `MainActivity`, `java` класс, который отправляет запрос в сеть и получает оттуда ответ. Работает все так:

1.`MainActivity` -> 2.`LClass` -> 3.`Internet` -> 4.`LClass` -> 5.`MainActivity`

1. Вызываю метод в `LClass`
2. Посылаю запрос на сервер
3. Принимаю через несколько миллисекунд ответ
4. Отправляю ответ в `MainActivity`
5. Выполняю определенный код

Моя проблема в том, что не могу написать правильный `callback`, который бы решил мой вопрос. 
Читал уроки в сети по callback'ам - ничего не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Код будет следующим:

1. Создаем интерфейс `DataInterface`

```
public interface DataInterface {

    void getDataInterface(List dataList);
    void getOnFailureMessage(String failureMessage);
}
```

2. В существующей активити `MainActivity` пишу

```
// вариант #1
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // методы класса

    private DataInterface dataInterface = new DataInterface() {
        @Override
        public void getDataInterface(List dataList) {
            // здесь делаю все, что мне нужно с dataList
        }

        @Override
        public void getOnFailureMessage(String failureMessage) {
            // здесь обрабатываю ошибки, которые могут возникнуть при работе с сетью
        }
    };

    // к примеру, ВЫЗОВ будет в onCreate() activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

        GetData.getData(dataInterface);

    }

    // методы класса

}
```

3. В `java` классе, который работает с `Retrofit 2` пишу в методе `onResponse()`

```
public class GetData {

    public static void getData(final DataInterface dataInterface) {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(...., @NonNull Response response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
            List data = response.body().getData();
            dataInterface.getDataInterface(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(... , @NonNull Throwable t) {
        dataInterface.getOnFailureMessage(t.toString());
    }
}
```

Вот и все! Оказалось проще простого! Будет в сети теперь +1 адекватный пример кода

// Везде в коде вместо `List dataList` прописан `List<Data> dataList`

Answer (score 1):

Если по простому колбек это, когда не ты вызываешь метод(new SomeClass().someMethod()), а у тебя вызовут метод. Сразу вопрос, кто его должен вызвать? Так вот вызовет, тот обьект на которого ты подписан.
Пример:
Ты едешь в автобусе. Если использовать первый вариант, то тебе придется самому опрашивать кондуктора можно ли ему заплатить за проезд. При использовании колбека ты заходя в автобус регистрируешся, как человек, который хочет заплатить за проезд. Так вот тебе постоянно опрашивать теперь кондуктора не нужно. Когда придет нужное время, кондуктор сам вызовет у тебя метод взятьДеньгиЗаПроезд()
Изходя из вышенаписаного сделай класс LClass слушателя и MainActivity подписчиком, и зарегистрируй MainActivity у LClass. Как это сделать есть куча примеров в инете, почитай про observer и listener

```
public class Subscriber implements Listener {
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        System.out.println("I've been called!");
    }
}

interface Listener {
    void onEvent();
}

class EventCatcher {
    private List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) {
        subscribers.add(subscriber);
    }

    public void removeSubscriber(Subscriber subscriber) {
        subscribers.remove(subscriber);
    }

    public void catchEvent() {
        System.out.println("Event happened!");
        for (Subscriber subscriber : subscribers) {
            subscriber.onEvent();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
        EventCatcher eventCatcher = new EventCatcher();
        eventCatcher.addSubscriber(subscriber);

        System.out.println("Event is coming!");

        eventCatcher.catchEvent();
    }
}
```

Output:

*Event is coming!

Event happened!

I've been called!*

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы ты мне помог с кодом. Это сильно сэкономит время.

Comment: Благодарю за код. Пока он еще сложноват для меня :-) Но +1 все равно поставлю)))